# Как разделить строку Python

Tags: python, строки, list, split

В переменной `chess` мы получаем какой-то любой фрагмент шахматной партии.
Например:

```
chess = '1. d2 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Кc3 c5 4. Кf3 Кc6 5. e:d5 e:d5 6. Сe2 Кf6 7. O-O Сe7 8. Сg5 O-O 9. d:c5 Сe6 10. Кd4 С:c5 11. Кb3 Сe7 12. Сf3 Кe5 13. Лe1 К:f3+ 14. Ф:f3 Лc8 15. h3 h6'
```

Как можно разделить строку чтобы распечатать ход первой партии? Мне нужно разделить все партии чтобы выглядело так:

```
['1. d2 e6', '2. e4 d5', '3. Кc3 c5', .... ]
```

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте так:

```
def f(chess):
    chess = chess.split()
    return [" ".join(chess[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(chess), 3)]

chess = '1. d2 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Кc3 c5 4. Кf3 Кc6 5. e:d5 e:d5 6. Сe2 Кf6 7. O-O Сe7 8. Сg5 O-O 9. d:c5 Сe6 10. Кd4 С:c5 11. Кb3 Сe7 12. Сf3 Кe5 13. Лe1 К:f3+ 14. Ф:f3 Лc8 15. h3 h6'
print(f(chess))
```

Comment: просто и красиво

Answer (score 4):

```
import re        
re.split(r'\s+?\b(?=\d+\.)', chess)


['1. d2 e6',
 '2. e4 d5',
 '3. Кc3 c5',
...
```

Comment: Благодарю за ваши ответы! Скажите, а просто с помощью split и join без def можно ли это сделать?

Comment: так просто не делайте функцию из второго ответа